# array in array in array and also one

Tags: c#

I need to write a factorial using an array but the problem is only Show **120** five times and what i want is  **1, 2, 6, 24, 120** showing in the textBox

```
int factProg = 1;
public void factArray(int[] arr)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        factProg = factProg * arr[i];
    }
}



int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    factArray(arr);
    textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(factProg);
    textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Does this even compile? UPD: forgot about methods inside methods, but that is some amazing code style.

Comment: You are having two loops, ofcourse it will print 120 five times

Comment: i want factorial from 1 to 5 showing in the textbox @someone using this method

Comment: so how I can fix it @OfirWinegarten ?

Comment: Rather than calculating a factorial for each n from 1 to 5, you calculate the product of array [1,2,3,4,5] 5 times. You could use `int fact(int i)=>i*fact(i-1);` and then in the `for` loop `fact(arr[i])` instead of `factArray(arr)`

Comment: get rid of the main loop and instead return an array (or string) from the `factArray` method

Comment: can you Answer and fix the code. so I can understand what you mean  @someone

Comment: i'll try @OfirWinegarten

Comment: [A pastebin](https://pastebin.com/u6aAkrMR)

Comment: Expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration) @someone after pasting the code this error showing

Comment: On which line? Are you using C# 7?

Comment: in this line ` int fact(int num) => num * fact(num - 1);` i'm using VS 2015 @someone

Comment: Move it outside of the current method.

Comment: thank you @someone

Comment: @john Why did you change your title to something so nonsensical? And why did you try to [retag](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47346657/5) this as php? Why not title it something that makes sense, for example: "How to get all factorial values for number"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put - your factArray method always calculates the factorial for the length of the whole array which is a fixed size. You need to pass an extra parameter - being the position in the array you want to stop calculating

Try this if you want to calculate using your array :

```
int factProg;
public void factArray(int[] arr, int len)
{   
  factProg = arr[0];
  for (int i = 1; i <= len; i++)
  {
    factProg = factProg * arr[i];
  }
}

int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
  factArray(arr, i);
  textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(factProg);
  textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
}
```

You would need to add a check in the method that you are not exceeding the array length.

Comment: Code cleanup suggestion: make `factProg` local to the method and `return` its value.

Comment: @HansKesting: I deliberately kept the code as close as possible to the original - but that's not the only thing I would do to clean up the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code below

```
public static void FactorialJohn(int[] arr)
            {          

                List<int> Resarr = new List<int>();
                arr.ToList().ForEach(x => Resarr.Add(Enumerable.Range(1, x).Aggregate((a, b) => a * b)));

                foreach (var item in Resarr)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
```

The above code gets you factorial of every element in the array.

Comment: @John The above code will get you the same result using Linq